# A RenderFlex overflowed by 99639 pixels on the right

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm trying to make a sentence in the center of the page and an icon button at the top left to go back to the main page but it showed this. Would appreciate your help :) (using a Pixel 4 XL API 30)

[image: open here]

here's the full code for this page

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ShoppingCart extends StatefulWidget {


  @override
  _ShoppingCartState createState() => _ShoppingCartState();
}

class _ShoppingCartState extends State<ShoppingCart> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          Flexible(
            flex: 1,
            child: Center(
              child: Text('No orders yet...',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 20,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.4)
              ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(
              top: MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top,
              left: 25,
              right: 25
            ),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                Container(
                  child: IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios),
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.pop(context);
                    },
                    color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.7),
                    iconSize: 19,
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Add your whole widget in a `Material` widget to see if it resolves your issue.

Comment: ah okay and where do i add the Material widget sorry i'm still new in Flutter

Comment: It can be the parent of the whole screen. You can remove the top `Container` and add a `Material` instead, since it doesn't do anything anyway (the top `Container` widget).

Comment: ah yesss it worked thank you so much ^^

Comment: Awesome glad I helped, happy Flutter jouney ^^

Comment: May I suggest adding the answer as actual anwer and accept it so the Question is marked as such in SO? :)